# Jquery - remove one the form elements

Tags: jquery, duplicates

I am working with some pretty bad legacy code and I have this function that returns a dialogue the issue is that the dialogue contains duplicate forms - they are the exact same form. So I have something like:

```
<div id="bla">
    <form> ... </form> 
    <form> ... </form>
</div>
```

This comes in as a `data` object, so when I do `console.log(data);` I get output simmilar to what you see above. Now i tried doing:

`data = $("form").get();`

Which kind of works, but in order for the dialog to open I need the wrapping div. So essentially what I want is:

```
<div id="bla">
    <form> ... </form> 
</div>
```

Any ideas? I have tried going back and fixing this issue in the code base but that would take more time then if there was a simple fix for this issue.

**Update**

I apologize, I was not clear enough with how this dialog gets it's data. To pass in data I do the following:

```
 self.load = function(noteId){
        if(noteId === undefined){
            noteId = 0;
        }

        CT.postSynch('site/manage/createSiteMaintenanceForm', {}, function(data){
            self.remove();
            $('body').append(data);
            self.init();
            self.show();
        });

        return self;
    }
```

The part to focus on is `$('body').append(data);` when we `console.log(data)` we get the above output of double forms.

Comment: Assuming your data is just HTML, would something like `$(data).find('form').first().remove()` an option?  If you have no use for one of the forms and can discard it.

Comment: problem with that is that if the form is out side the <div id="bla"> it too is also deleted. So I kinda of need this to only affect stuff inside of bla, could I do: `find(#bla form)`??

Comment: Yeah, `.find('#bla form')` is definitely an option if you need to narrow the focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data is just a plain HTML string, could you try this:

```
CT.postSynch('site/manage/createSiteMaintenanceForm', {}, function(data){
        self.remove();
        var $data = $(data);

        $data.find('#bla form').first().remove();
        $data.appendTo('body');
        self.init();
        self.show();
    });
```

Based off a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ekcrh/) I just mocked up.

Comment: Dialog does not open now ... should it append, then search and remove? I should also add that yes it is just a string of html.

Comment: Sorry, I clearly shouldn't answer tired.  With jQuery you're quite welcome to treat a string wrapped in jQuery `$()` as DOM, and this is typically better practice than touching the DOM again after appending.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following code. For example, if your forms are like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <form action="ACTION">Hello</form>
    <form action="ACTION">Hello 2</form>
</div>
```

Then the only jQuery you need is the following:

```
$('#container').find(">:first-child").remove();
```

Alternatively, if the containing div has a distinctive name, you could use this also:

```
$('#container form').first().remove();
```

Let me know if this helps!

QUICK EDIT: A better solution, combining them:

```
$('#container').find('form').first().remove();
```

Comment: I updated my OP. I tried your stuff after `$('body').append(data)` but it didn't work... The dialog opened  with two forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply: `$('#bla form').eq(1).remove();`

[example](http://jsbin.com/UGUnEzi/1/edit)

<sub>Docs: 
http://api.jquery.com/eq/
 http://api.jquery.com/remove/</sub>

Comment: I updated my OP. I tried your stuff after `$('body').append(data)` but it didn't work... The dialog opened  with two forms.